# Wireshark frame.time_relative vs. tcp.time_relative

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I am trying to analyze TCP traffic using Wireshark. Currently, I am trying to get a better understanding of the time fields that are provided, namely `frame.time_relative` and `tcp.time_relative`.

After reading the documentation and dumping the trace into a JSON file with:

```
tshark -r trace.raw -T json -e frame.time_relative -e frame.time_delta -e tcp.time_relative -e tcp.time_delta
```

I get the impression that `frame.time_relative` and `tcp.time_relative` are the same. Is that correct? And if so, why do they both exist?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're not the same. According to the documentation, [`frame.time_relative`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/f/frame.html) gives the time since it received the **first frame in the packet**, whereas [`tcp.time_relative`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/t/tcp.html) gives the time since it received the **first frame in the TCP session**. Since you might have several packets in a TCP session, `tcp.time_relative` may refer to a prior packet (`tcp.time_relative >= frame.time_relative`).

Comment: thx you are right, I misread it in the documentation the first couple of times